# How to move featured image to the top of the list?

Tags: jquery, post-thumbnails, filters

I have been working on using featured image to create a list of items on the right column here:

http://www.julianamaeberger.com/soma/news/

The current featured image is now being given a class of "highlighted" so that you can tell which image is related to the post. I now need to move that li class="highlighted" to the top of the list so that it's always visible.

Is jquery sortable the best option here?

Thanks for any help in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you do this in HTML? So instead of printing everything in your loop, append it to a string that you print in the end. That way you can keep special stuff apart.

I assume this is a follow-up question to your previous question about featured images, so I will use [the code from my answer there](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5238/how-to-show-a-featured-image-as-current/5267#5267) as an example.

```
<?php
$testimonials = get_posts( array(
    'category_name' => 'testimonial',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'order' => 'DESC'
) );
$highlighted_testimonial_thumbnail = '';
$other_testimonial_thumbnails = '';
foreach ( $testimonials as $testimonial ) {
    if ( $testimonial->ID == $current_testimonial_id ) {
        $highlighted_testimonial_thumbnail = '<li class="highlighted">' . get_the_post_thumbnail( $testimonial->ID, 'nav' ) . '</li>';
    } else {
        $other_testimonial_thumbnails .= '<li>' . get_the_post_thumbnail( $testimonial->ID, 'nav' ) . '</li>';
    }
}
echo '<ul class="portfolio">';
echo $highlighted_testimonial_thumbnail;
echo $other_testimonial_thumbnails;
echo '</ul>';
```

Or more generic: instead of:

```
foreach ( $array_of_stuff as $stuff ) {
    echo $stuff
}
```

Do it like this:

```
$output = '';
$featured_output = '';
foreach ( $array_of_stuff as $stuff ) {
    if ( is_featured( $stuff ) ) {
        $featured_output = $stuff;
    } else {
        $output .= $stuff;
    }
}

echo $featured_output;
echo $output;
```

Almost all functions in WordPress that echo something have an equivalent that doesn't echo but just returns it. [`get_the_content()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_content) vs [`the_content()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content) for example.

Comment: I had a feeling I was looking at this from the wrong angle. This worked perfected!

Comment: I did notice you added to your response - I had spent a day watching intro PHP tutorials to try to understand the first response, which turned out to be a good idea, in any case. This morning I saw that you edited your response and that was super helpful. I'm curious if you can recommend any resources on PHP and Wordpress development. I was maybe going to post this as an additional question, but I'm not sure if it's appropriate for this forum. It said it might be flagged as subjective.

Comment: @user1858: I could find at least two questions on this site about training material: [one about books](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1121/recommendations-for-an-in-depth-wordpress-book) and [one about generic material](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5861/wordpress-training-materials). I hope this helps you. And welcome to this site! I hope to see more good questions and answers from do. Do you have a username to use instead of the generic `user1858`?